# Error "Google Cloud Platform project quota exceeded."

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In Google tag manager I created a container and clicked "Automatically Provision Tagging Server", seleted a billing profile and it keeps showing the following error `Google Cloud Platform project quota exceeded.`

I verified an quota is not exceeded and tried creating a new billing profile but it still doesn't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have reached the maximum of 10 projects in my GCP account, so tag manager was not able to automatically create an additional project. Wish the error was a bit more explicit though.

Comment: I would recommend contacting GCP Support. They may hard delete your proyects.